# How to maintain an HTTPS connection with PHP Includes

Tags: php, url, https, include

I currently have a website setup on a Secure server.

When I go to my website, the browser will show the HTTPS secure connection symbol at the start of the page load, but then the symbol will be crossed out (google chrome) or disappear (safari) once the page fully loads.

I understand that any files that are not linked to the particular page through an HTTPS path will cause the page to not be considered secure.

I have setup all of my CSS and JavaScript files as being accessed through https://www.example.com/file however I understand that all of my PHP includes must also be accessed through the HTTPS secure path.

When I set my php.ini file to "allow_url_include = on" it still does not permit me to include using a URL path. I additionally have the "allow_url_fopen = on" set as well, but I am still not able to URL include using https://www.example.com.

Can someone explain to me how I can make it work so that every PHP include is included via HTTPS, so that all of my pages will be shown as HTTPS in a user's browser? (this is an ecommerce website, so this factor is important for my users to see).

Comment: PHP includes don't affect this. They happen on the server, so the browser isn't even aware of them. The browser only cares if client-side includes (images, scripts, styles, etc.) are served over HTTP.

Comment: Thank you. That does help me to understand how the Browser catches the HTTPS signature. However even with all images, JS, and HTML linked files (CSS), I am still getting the canceled out HTTPS.

Comment: I found an image that was not being inserted via HTTPS. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have setup all of my CSS and JavaScript files as being accessed through https://www.example.com/file

Good.

You also need to do that for all your images, and any other resources that get included.

> however I understand that all of my PHP includes must also be accessed through the HTTPS secure path.

In general, PHP includes should be done from the file system and not hit HTTP(S) at all (since that is inefficient).

The browser can't see what PHP does though, so it isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: I have gone through and setup all images to be accessed via HTTPS, however I am still getting the issue. Now I do include the GoDaddy secured and verified badges as well as authorize.net's badge also via their respective Javascript setups. Could that be a cause of the issue as well?

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I was able to find the Image that was not being connected via HTTPS.